# drupal 7 configure user registration process

Tags: drupal-modules, drupal-7, user-registration, drupal-hooks

I want a user registration process where the email sent to the user at various conditions (e.g. registration, approval) also contains some attachments depending on user profile.

Which file in Drupal core should I modify to configure the subject, body and add the attachment in an email based on user profile?

I add a custom module for this? If yes, then which hook am I looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Modifying drupal core is really a bad idea; you can simply create your own module, and use [hook_mail()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_mail/6).

Answer (score 0):

In your module you will need

```
hook_form_alter()
```

to enter your own submission handler in #submit array in the $form array of the specified form (or unset the one that is executed... copy it and make your own)
and in that handler you could use

```
hook_mail()
```

to form your own email with the values submitted from the form contained in $form_state array, or anything else!